# Delete route inside are u sure deleting wrong id, on the table

Tags: flask

I have converted my project into blueprints, and i found myself with a syntax problem i just dont know how to call my delete function with a passed variable when it is on blueprint, this is causing an issue where it is deleting the wrong data id.

This is my antique call

```
<a href= '/Deleta/{{Dado.id}}'type="button" class="btn btn-light">Sim </a>
```

And this is my route.

```
 @Tabelas.route('/Deleta/<int:id>')
 def Deleta(id):
   deletalinha = Dado.query.get_or_404(id)
    try:
      db.session.delete(deletalinha)
      db.session.commit()
      return redirect(url_for('Tabelas.TerceiraJanela') )
    except:
      return 'Ouve um problema deletando essa linha!'
```

And here is the entire table is worth noting the query is being displayed, and is looping through the data. Also there is a are u sure modal which i think is now the causer.

```
<tbody>
    <tr>    
        {% for Dado in Query %}
        <td>
            {{ Dado.MarcaDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.ModeloDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.VersaoDoMotorDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.TipoDeCombustivelDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.AnoDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.QuilometragemDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.PrecoDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.CorDB }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ Dado.MargemDeLucroDB }}
            {{ PresentePython }}
        </td>
        <td>
            <!-- Button trigger modal -->
            <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm py-1' data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"><span style="font-size: 10px; height: auto; font-weight: bold;">X</span></button> 
        </td>
            <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content bg-dark">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Deletar Dado</h5>
                <!-- Tags do botão X referente ao "Are you sure?"-->
                <button type="button" class="close d-none" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
              Você deseja deletar o dado?
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <a href= '/Deleta/{{Dado.id}}'type="button" class="btn btn-light">Sim </a>
              </div>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Comment: Can you provide more info on the issue? Does it delete another id? Which id does it delete? What tests have you tried? ...?

Comment: Well at first, i tried taking out the are u sure modal. Which basically popups the yes button which calls the route. And that worked out now it deletes the right id, real weird problem is,  the yes button inside are u sure also works but it deletes the last inserted id, not the correct one.

Comment: can't help without the html code you are speaking about

Comment: Oh okay lemme just patch the question.